# How to share files with uTorrent if you have a dynamic IP?

Tags: windows, utorrent

I want to create a .torrent file with uTorrent to send my friend some files. I've heard I need a DNS address so I made a host at no-ip.com

I added hxxp://dns-address:port/announce when I created the file. But after I open it @ status appears : HTTP Error 300. I gave my friend the .torrent file but it won't start.

What's the problem?

Comment: It is IP, not Ip. Just about everyone has as dynamically assigned IP, by the way. You *do not* need a fixed IP, nor a tracker, to serve a BitTorrent file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedded tracker must be enabled in: µTorrent menu > options > preferences > Advanced > bt.enable_tracker: set to "true".

Comment: Thanks guys. I found this on uTorrent's website. Works now :)

Comment: That isn't needed at all. You do not need a tracker with uTorrent, unless you are planning on mass distribution (for which a Tracker is a great help).

Comment: No, it's and Embeded Tracker in uTorrent. Special for this kind of situations :)

Comment: Read my comment. I am not saying that enabling the built-in Tracker in uTorrent isn't possible, nor asking what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you had the address correct, although I'm not sure why you substituted hxxp for http.  Do you have the no-ip service running on your system?  Has no-ip updated your IP address correctly?  You can verify that it has the right address by running the following command from a command prompt:

```
nslookup host.no-ip.com
```

Next, make sure that you have the proper ports forwarded through your NAT firewall.

It will also help to know the exact error utorrent is getting when your friend tries to connect -- is there anything more than just "HTTP Error 300?"

Comment: Just that error !

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things. Just create a .torrent (make it private or not, it doesn't matter), do not set any Tracker information, it isn't really needed for the use you want. Once the .torrent file is created, double click it and let it load. Leave your client (µTorrent) running. Send the .torrent to your friend and it will just work fine.

µTorrent uses DHT (please, instruct yourselves on the [BitTorrent protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol))), which makes it very easy to use, on a trackerless environment.